# Using two apis one with object id and another with name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mean-stack

I have two api calls to retrieve data from the same collection using different parameters.

The first one is by the ObjectID:

```
app.get('/api/employees/:id', function(req, res){
    Employee.findOne({_id:req.params.id}, function(err, employee){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(employee);
  }); });
```

And the second one retrieves data by the name :

```
app.get('/api/employees/:name', function(req, res){
    Employee.findOne({name:req.params.name}, function(err, employee){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(employee);
   });});
```

I placed both Apis in my code, but only the first one is being called. If I run my code I have something like:

```
{
    "_id": "58b00dd47689fc2f48b9baf4",
    "name": "Rohtih",
    "dept": "CSE",
    "area": "Banglore",
    "contact": "9962938489",
    "status": "System Engineer",
    "salary": "30000",
    "__v": 0
},
```

My mongo collection looks Like this:

```
{
    "_id": "58b00dd47689fc2f48b9baf4",
    "name": "Rohtih",
    "dept": "CSE",
    "area": "Banglore",
    "contact": "9962",
    "status": "System Engineer",
    "salary": "30000",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "58b00df07689fc2f48b9baf5",
    "name": "Vaibhav",
    "dept": "CSE",
    "area": "Banglore",
    "contact": "819",
    "status": "Manager",
    "salary": "300000",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I would like to know how do I use both apis at a time? Is there a mistake in my code, please help me solving this?

Comment: So, what's wrong?

Comment: If I include both api's in my server.js only one is working. How to use both apis at a time?

Comment: In what way does only one work? Does the other start throwing errors, or returning incorrect data? Is it always the same one which does not work, or is it sometimes one and sometimes the other? It's difficult for anybody to help constructively without all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand from your code, you may receive both parameters but you don't know when to use what. What I would separate in two different api calls:

First one is to find by Id:

```
app.get('/api/employees/findById', function(req, res){
  Employee.findOne({_id:req.params.id}, function(err, employee){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json(employee);
  }); });
```

Second one is to find by name:

```
app.get('/api/employees/findByName', function(req, res){
  Employee.findOne({name:req.params.name}, function(err, employee){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json(employee);
  });});
```

If you don't like any of those approaches, you can leave as it is and verify if the parameters are present, for example:

```
app.get('/api/employees/find', function(req, res){
  let name = req.params.name;
  let id = req.params.id;
  if(name !== undefined) {
     //Find By name here
  } else if(id !== undefined) {
    //Find by id here
  }
}
```

Hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is determine the value of the `req.params.id` string if it's a valid `ObjectId` and then create a query based on the outcome. For example:

```
app.get('/api/employees/:id', function(req, res){
    var query = {};
    if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
        query._id = req.params.id;
    } else {
        query.name = req.params.id;
    }

    Employee.findOne(query, function(err, employee){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(employee);
    });
});
```